# Oracle 11 - GROUP BY in a LEFT JOIN not working

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a list of 3 IDs - 110098016, 110098017 and 110098021. All three of IDs are linked to the same Order (wiporderno).

I'm trying to place the ID that's sequentially less to it beside it in another column.

[image: 110098016 and NULL 110098017 and 110098016 110098021 amd 110098021]

Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 (updating is sadly not possible)

The following segment of code runs and...

```
SELECT 
    ILV_L.ID
    ,ILVP.ID
    ,ILVP.rn
    ,ILV_L.wiporderno
FROM ILV_Labor ILV_L
LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            p.ID
            ,p.wiporderno
            ,MAX(p.rn) rn
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                ILVPP.ID
                ,ILVPP.wiporderno
                ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ILVPP.wiporderno ORDER BY ILVPP.ID ASC) AS rn
            FROM ILV_Labor ILVPP) p
        GROUP BY id, wiporderno) ILVP       
    ON ILVP.ID < ILV_L.ID
        AND ILVP.wiporderno = ILV_L.wiporderno
        --AND (h.rn = 1 OR h.rn IS NULL)
```

... returns this.

[image: Output]

For some unknown reason, the GROUP BY & MAX statement will not work. Grouping by the max should have filtered out where 110098021 is matched to 110098016 (i.e. where rn = 1 for 110098021). The following statement without the GROUP BY returns the *exact* same result.

```
SELECT 
    ILV_L.ID
    ,ILVP.ID
    ,ILVP.rn
    ,ILV_L.wiporderno
FROM ILV_Labor ILV_L
LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
                ILVPP.ID
                ,ILVPP.wiporderno
                ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ILVPP.wiporderno ORDER BY ILVPP.ID ASC) AS rn
            FROM ILV_Labor ILVPP) ILVP       
    ON ILVP.ID < ILV_L.ID
        AND ILVP.wiporderno = ILV_L.wiporderno
```

[image: Output]

Is there something happening, potentially with the compiler, that prevents this GROUP BY from working?

Comment: please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: Sample data, desired results, please.  At a guess, your join isn't doing what you think - ` ON ILVP.ID < ILV_L.ID` makes me suspicious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` is void. If you group by the table's ID, then you get one result row per ID. This is the same rows as in the original table, because the ID is unique. No aggregations takes place really.

If there is just one row per order in the table as in the sample data you have shown us, and you want the previous order, use `LAG`.

```
select l.*, lag(wiporderno) over (order by id) as previous_wiporderno
from ilv_labor l
order by id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query is "working" without any bugs as the inner query:

```sql
SELECT ID
     , wiporderno
     , MAX(rn) rn
FROM   (
  SELECT ID
       , wiporderno
       , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY wiporderno ORDER BY ID ASC) AS rn
  FROM   ILV_Labor
)
GROUP BY
       id
     , wiporderno
```

Will return 3 rows:

| ID | WIPORDERNO | RN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 110098016 | X | 1 |
| 110098017 | X | 2 |
| 110098021 | X | something |

Then when you join it to the outer query:

```sql
SELECT ILV_L.ID
     , ILVP.ID
     , ILVP.rn
     , ILV_L.wiporderno
FROM   ILV_Labor ILV_L
       LEFT JOIN <inner_query> ILVP       
       ON (   ILVP.ID < ILV_L.ID
          AND ILVP.wiporderno = ILV_L.wiporderno );
```

Then you state in the question that the `wiporderno`s are the same so the join is effectively on `ILVP.ID < ILV_L.ID` and for the `ILV_L.ID` value of `110098021` you will get 1 row from the left table matching 2 rows from the right table (since both `110098016` and `110098017` are less than `110098021`).

It may not be doing what you intend but it is doing exactly what you have asked.